# Binding refreshes all bound controls on animation

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

When using a color binding like

```
Background="{Binding Design.LeftBarColor}"
```

and executing an animation like

```
<DoubleAnimation From="1" To="0.5" Storyboard.TargetName="appName"
    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Label.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Opacity)"
    Duration="0:0:0.25"/>
```

all of the controls Binding to "Design.LeftBarColor" are refreshed. But I only want to refresh the label's (appName) background color. I just tried to change the binding mode, but this did not work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of directly using the `Design.LeftBarColor` Brush for the Background of the Label, you could create a new Background brush for every Label, and bind the new Brush's Color to `Design.LeftBarColor.Color`.

```
<Label Name="appName" ...>
    <Label.Background>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Design.LeftBarColor.Color}"/>
    </Label.Background>
   ...
</Label>
```

Comment: It is almost the same as Rene's answer:

Nice idea, but setting the UIElements opacity does not affect the labels background color - I do not want to change the label's text opacity

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if i am correct about what you are trying to do. I would say if you want to fade out a control on animation, do not target the brush's opacity. Put a border control on top of the label, and modify the border's opacity.

Sample code here:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MyBrush" Color="Red"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Border Name="Container">
            <Label Background="{StaticResource MyBrush}">
                <Label.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Rectangle.Loaded">
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation
            Storyboard.TargetName="Container" 
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
            From="1.0" To="0.0" Duration="0:0:5" 
            AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
                </Label.Triggers>
                Lorem ipsum
            </Label>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Nice idea, but setting the borders opacity does not affect the labels background color - I do not want to change the label's text opacity.